# Controller-factory-view syncronization

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble with data synchronization between factory, controller and view. What happens is that the variable $scope.supermarket is initialized after the view is loaded.

I have implemented factory like this:

```
var main_module = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
main_module.factory('dataFactory', ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q){

    var dataFactory = {};
    dataFactory.getSupermarkets = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/supermarkets/")
            .then(function(response){
                defer.resolve(response.data);
             }, function(error){
                defer.reject(error);
             });

        return defer.promise;
    };

    dataFactory.getEmployees = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/employees/")
            .then(function(response){
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            }, function(error){
                defer.reject(error);
            });

        return defer.promise;
    };

    return dataFactory;
}
```

And this is my controller implementation:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var main_module = angular.module("myApp");

main_module.controller("EmployeeController", ["$scope", "$http", "dataFactory", function($scope, $http, dataFactory){

    $scope.employees = [];
    dataFactory.getEmployees().then(function(data){
            $scope.employees = data;
        }, function(error){
           lert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );
    $scope.supermarkets = [];
    dataFactory.getSupermarkets().then(function(data){
            $scope.supermarkets = data;
        }, function(error){
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );
}]);

}());
```

The view part that uses $scope.supermarket variable is this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">SUPERMARKET:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="s.name in supermarkets" ng-model="newEmployee.supermarket"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The select field is always empty after the view is loaded.

I'm still in the process of learning AngularJS, so any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Any error in the console? Have you checked the network tab to see if the request for the supermarkets was sent, and if it returned a non-empty array? Have you tried debugging your code? Note that your promise code uses an antipattern. Use chaining: `return $http.get('...').then(function(response) { return response.data; });`

Comment: OK, I reimplemented my both of my factory methods as you suggested and that ng-options part as @Moncef Hassein-bey said, and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not returnig the local dataFactory object in dataFactory.

```
var main_module = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
main_module.factory('dataFactory', ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q){

    var dataFactory = {};
    dataFactory.getSupermarkets = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/supermarkets/")
            .then(function(response){
                defer.resolve(response.data);
             }, function(error){
                defer.reject(error);
             });

        return defer.promise;
    };

    dataFactory.getEmployees = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/employees/")
            .then(function(response){
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            }, function(error){
                defer.reject(error);
            });

        return defer.promise;
    };

    return dataFactory; // missing
}
```

Not relative to the problem : why you define var main_module ?? I do not see the need for this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy that line. It is actually there. I edited the question.
I'll remove that declaration line, thanks.

Comment: +1, @JB Nizet, include your console error. But, I can see also another problem in ng-options it should be like : ng-options="s.name for s in supermarkets"

Comment: I edited view as last comment suggested. This is my server response:
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Super-market","location":"Somewhere"}],"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/supermarkets/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: OK, I reimplemented my both of my factory methods as @JB Nizet suggested and that ng-options part as you said and it works now. I guess problem was with that "defer" thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several mistakes in this code.

1.Your are not added the ng-controller directive into the view.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

2.newEmployee.supermarket is missing in the $scope. Please refer to the angular document
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Try to print the response in the view 
{{ newEmployee.supermarket | json }}

Comment: I use $routeProvider to set controller to the view. The code sections I provided are just a part of the view and of the controller, so newEmploye is actually defined.